# date_trunc org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I get this error while running this Java/JDBC code. Any ideas how to get around it?

Seems like it's complaining about the parameter in date_trunc function?

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"**
Position: 100

```
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryEx
ecutorImpl.java:2161)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutor
Impl.java:1890)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.ja
va:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Stat
ement.java:560)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(Abstract
Jdbc2Statement.java:417)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc
2Statement.java:302)
```

Java code:

```
static PreparedStatement searchErrorPP = connection.prepareStatement(
"select count(*) from tracking where date_trunc('day', run_date) <= 
     date_trunc('day', timestamp ?)");



public static int queryCount(java.util.Date date) throws SQLException {


  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  try {
      ps = searchErrorPP;
      ps.setDate( 1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
      ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

resulting query which executes fine in pgAdmin:

```
select count(*) from tracking where date_trunc('day', run_date) <= 
           date_trunc('day', timestamp '2014-11-11 -05:00:00')
```

Comment: Can you simplify the query to just enough to trigger the error? Do you really need to use timestamp casts and `date_trunc` when you already have dates? PostgreSQL uses numbered placeholders natively (`$1`, `$2`, ...) so the `?` placeholders are presumably converted to numbered placeholders internally, hence the `$2` in the error message.

Comment: @mu is too short: ok updated the question w/ a shorter query.

Comment: @mu is too short: I'm actually porting Oracle specific Java code to Postgres so I substituted Oracle's `trunc` w/ POstgres' `date_trunc` to achieve the same result. The query worked fine in principle so I'm trying to integrate it in Java. If it doesn't work I might try what you said i.e., work with Date objects directly and not use date_trunc.

Comment: Is it any happier with `?::timestamp` or `cast(? as timestamp)`? I don't have all the Java stuff set up so I'm just making some guesses.

Comment: I updated the Java exception posted, does 'receiveErrorResponse' mean the query was executed fine but post-processing failed?

Comment: standalone query with `?::timestamp` runs fine but JDBC PreparedStatement fails

Comment: `cast(? as timestamp)` worked! thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using the `type 'string'` syntax as in `timestamp '2014-11-11 -05:00:00'`, the value provided must be a constant, not a parameter. It's interpreted and converted to an internal timestamp representation by the SQL engine at the parse stage, before actual execution takes place and before the values for the parameters are known.

So when encountering `timestamp $1`, the parser produces a syntax error because `$1` is not a literal string.

On the other hand, the value of `cast($1 as timestamp)` will be produced at execute stage, so this is what should be used.

As for the syntax from the point of view of JDBC, `cast(? as timestamp)` should be fine. The PostgreSQL specific syntax `?::timestamp` with double colons also probably works.

Comment: `cast(? as timestamp)` worked, thanks also for the explanation! @mu is too short also suggested the same but I gave up a little early.

Comment: `?::timestamp` did not work for me, it actually worked in standalone query but not thru JDBC.

Comment: @sv. the `::type` syntax is a PostgreSQL-specific cast so it could be confusing something inside JDBC-land, `cast(? as type)` is standard SQL. Anyway, glad you got it all sorted out.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem with INTERVAL and using cast(:seasonInterval as INTERVAL) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such an error when either of the jdbc connection url components are null.

E.g. connection url components such as DB host name, dbname, user or password are null.

Please check out there and you should find a clue.